# TYPO3: string[] to Object[] Type Converter?

Tags: php, type-conversion, typo3

Right now I have a Type Converter, from `string` to my `User::class` set up like this. By the way, I simply use this for a User class that I have for some specific User objects which I don't want to persist, that's why it simply deserializes them:

```php
class UserConverter extends AbstractTypeConverter
{
    protected $priority = 1;
    protected $sourceTypes = ['string'];
    protected $targetType = User::class;


    public function convertFrom($source, string $targetType,
                                array $convertedChildProperties = [],
                                PropertyMappingConfigurationInterface $configuration = null)
    {
        return unserialize($source);
    }
}
```

And after registering it, it works as expected, e.g. from Fluid form to a Controller action the serialized object gets deserialized automatically.

This works for single properties such as for `$report->user`. I'm trying to achieve the same with array properties, e.g. `$report->users`. So I made:

```php
class UserArrayConverter extends AbstractTypeConverter
{
    protected $priority = 1;
    protected $sourceTypes = ['array'];
    protected $targetType = 'array';


    public function convertFrom($source, string $targetType,
                                array $convertedChildProperties = [],
                                PropertyMappingConfigurationInterface $configuration = null)
    {
        return ['TODO']; 
    }
}
```

But debuging that TODO line I see that the execution thread never reaches it. And of course I get my `$report->users` as an array of strings (serialized objects) instead of an array of Users.

How should I create the TypeConverter so it can convert an array of strings to an array of Users?

***TYPO3: 10.4, PHP: 7.4***

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should use your first property mapper and do the magic inside initializeAction.

```php
public function initialize<Whatever>Action()
{
    $propertyMapping = $this->arguments
        ->getArgument('report')
        ->getPropertyMappingConfiguration();
    $propertyMapping->forProperty('users')->allowAllProperties();
    $propertyMapping->forProperty('users')->setTypeConverterOptions(
            UserConverter::class
        );
}
```

Untested, but this should be the way.

Comment: Thanks for responding! But that seems to be missing the `$options` parameter, what should I pass there?

Comment: Sorry for responding that late. Which $options parameter do you mean?